# Grab camera position from plotly 3d graph

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I'm drawing plotly 3D graph and want to adjust camera position. The best way to do it for me is to use viewer, zoom and rotate scene as needed, then grab camera position as JSON and put it into my script that generate the picture to achieve the same position by default.

According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/plotlygraphs/status/602851657572048896), it should be working, but it doesn't.

My code is:

```
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter3d, Layout, Scene
from plotly.offline import iplot
import plotly
from numpy import sin, cos, linspace, pi, zeros_like

plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

t = linspace(0, 4*pi)

trace1 = Scatter3d(
    x = t,
    y = cos(t),
    z = sin(t),
    mode = 'lines'
)

layout = Layout(
                width = 600, 
                height = 600, 
                scene = Scene(
                    xaxis = {'title': 't'},
                    yaxis = {'title': 'x'},
                    zaxis = {'title': 'y'},
                    camera =
                      {'eye':{'x':0,'y':1,'z':0}, 
                       'up': {'x':0,'y':0,'z':1}, 
                       'center': {'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}}
                )
)
iplot(dict(data=[trace1], layout=layout))
```

Then I get a picture:

[image: iplot]

click 'save and edit in the cloud', switch to plotly interface, adjust camera position and click View JSON and still get the default camera position as I specified in Layout.

[image: json]

Comment: This is the intended behavior. plotly.js doesn't save the camera position before sending it to the plot.ly cloud. You'll need to save your graph on plot.ly/plot/ in order to update its `camera` attribute.

Comment: @etpinard, thanks! Now I see that if I save my plot in plot.ly web interface, then adjust camera, than save again, I get correct camera values in JSON preview. Could you please make an answer from this comment to allow me accepting it?

Comment: so how to get camera position with onClick event ?

Comment: Has this been updated since it was 6 years ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior.

plotly.js doesn't save the camera position before sending it to the plot.ly cloud. You'll need to save your graph in the plotly workspace at [plot.ly/plot](https://plot.ly/plot) in order to update its `camera` attribute.

Comment: 9 years later, the URL plot.ly/plot now 404's.  Curious what the current solution is.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a full explanation with examples of Plotly's camera controls for 3d plots:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/etpinard/plotly-misc-nbs/blob/master/3d-camera-controls.ipynb

For the sake of completeness, here is a short summary:

It is possible to use `camera` instead of `cameraposition` as it seems to have simpler explanation.

The camera position is determined by three vectors: `up`, `center`, `eye`.

The up vector determines the up direction on the page. The default is `(x=0, y=0, z=1)`, that is, the z-axis points up.

The center vector determines the translation about the center of the scene. By default, there is no translation: the center vector is `(x=0, y=0, z=0)`.

The eye vector determines the camera view point about the origin. The default is `(x=1.25, y=1.25, z=1.25)`.

It is also possible to zooming in by reducing the norm the eye vector.

```
name = 'eye = (x:0.1, y:0.1, z:1)'
camera = dict(
    up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1),
    center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
    eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1)
)
fig = make_fig(camera, name)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False, filename=name)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This can set the initial position, but the question was about how to get *new* camera position after interaction with mouse.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a plotly `figure`, you can use `FigureWidget` to get and set the camera view data interactively:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = px.scatter_3d(...)  # your plotly figure

f = go.FigureWidget(fig)
f  # to see the figure in the Jupyter Notebook. Can rotate as you like
```

```py
# Get the current orientation:
f.layout['scene']['camera']['eye']

# Set the current orientation:
f.layout['scene']['camera']['eye'] = dict(x=1.25, y=1.25, z=1.25)
```

---

Alternatives (to get) :

```py
f.layout['scene']['camera']['eye']._props
f.get_state()['_layout']['scene']['camera']['eye']
```

Sources:

https://community.plotly.com/t/getting-camera-view-data-for-3d-plots/18066

https://plotly.com/python/figurewidget/

Comment: Thank you Vladimir. I needed to recreate a very specific angle. An reading out the current orientiation of the go.FigureWidget made it easy.