# How cameraposition in plotly works

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I'm trying to plot 3D graphs with plotly and need to adjust camer position. I found that there's two ways to do it: either with `camera` attribute of `Scene` object, or with `cameraposition` attribute. I have problem with both, but this question is related to `cameraposition`: I can't figure out what does it mean.

The [docs](https://plot.ly/python/3d-plots-tutorial/) says:

```
 |      cameraposition [required=False] (value=camera position list or 1d numpy
 |      array):
 |          Sets the camera position with respect to the scene. The first entry
 |          (a list or 1d numpy array of length 4) sets the angular position of
 |          the camera. The second entry (a list or 1d numpy array of length 3)
 |          sets the (x,y,z) translation of the camera. The third entry (a
 |          scalar) sets zoom of the camera.
 |
 |          Examples:
 |              [[0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.2], [0.1, 0, -0.1], 3]
```

What 4 numbers of *angular position of the camera* mean? Are they angles? In radians? Which angles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an explanation of Plotly's camera controls for 3d plots:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/etpinard/plotly-misc-nbs/blob/master/3d-camera-controls.ipynb

For the sake of completeness, here is a short summary:

It is possible to use `camera` instead of `cameraposition` as it seems to have simpler explanation.

The camera position is determined by three vectors: `up`, `center`, `eye`.

The up vector determines the up direction on the page. The default is `(x=0, y=0, z=1)`, that is, the z-axis points up.

The center vector determines the translation about the center of the scene. By default, there is no translation: the center vector is `(x=0, y=0, z=0)`.

The eye vector determines the camera view point about the origin. The default is `(x=1.25, y=1.25, z=1.25)`.

It is also possible to zooming in by reducing the norm the eye vector.

```
name = 'eye = (x:0.1, y:0.1, z:1)'
camera = dict(
    up=dict(x=0, y=0, z=1),
    center=dict(x=0, y=0, z=0),
    eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1)
)
fig = make_fig(camera, name)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False, filename=name)
```

Comment: Oh, nice! It is not exactly the answer on my question, but it addressed my issue anyway :) Actually, I'm a bit confused between camera and cameraposition and thought about asking the second question about `camera` (how to zoom in with `camera`), and this is the answer to that unasked question. :) Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I proposed an edit to the answer, adding a summary of the page you linked as link-only answers are discouraged on SO.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the runaround. I copied here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478791/grab-camera-position-from-plotly-3d-graph/35497559#35497559
This will be added to the official Plotly Python docs tomorrow.

Comment: The `cameraposition` attribute has been deprecated [ref: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plots/gl3d/layout/layout_attributes.js#L161-L167)] Use `camera` instead.

Comment: Official documentation for camera angle controls is now here: https://plot.ly/python/3d-camera-controls/

Comment: `It is also possible to zooming in by reducing the norm the eye vector.` That should really be highlighted. Took me way too long to figure this out.